# Solving $\exp\bigg(\frac{2+\pi i}{4} \bigg)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> $\exp\bigg(\dfrac{2+\pi i}{4} \bigg)$

**My try:**

$=e^{(1/2)}e^{(\pi i)/4}$

$=e^{(1/2)}[\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)]$

> My try is correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My try is correct?

Comment: yes, it is quite right

Comment: To **solve** an **equation** you need an equality sign and one unknown variable such as $x$. You probably mean **simplify** this expression, or similar. Wording is useful, especially in exams, as it tells you what you need to do. Took me a while to realise that many moons ago :-)

Comment: @poirot English is'nt my first language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is correct, you may then use 
$$
\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2, \quad \sin(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2,
$$ to obtain
$$
\exp\bigg(\dfrac{2+\pi i}{4} \bigg)=\frac{\sqrt{2e}}2(1+i).
$$